# how to show message when I use *ngIf in html using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have a little problem when I use *ngIf

My ws get me all product, when ws get me 'no result' I want to show this message in my page. For this I try this code:

```
products: Product[]=[];
  getallproduct() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.ws.product(params['id']).subscribe(
          products=> {
            this.prod= products;
            console.log(products) // show all product or No result
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

In hmtl I have used this code to get all my product:

```
 <table *ngFor="let item of prod">
 <p *ngIf="prod === 0"> No result! </p>
 <tr>
   <td>{{item.id}}<td>
   <td>{{item.name}}<td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

When I use `*ngIf="prod === 0"` in html nothing happens. When I use `*ngIf="prod !== 0"` in html show *No result!*  when I have result. I want this message when prod are empty.

```
{StatusCode: 0, StatusMessage: "OK", StatusDescription: "No result"}
```

Please, can you suggest any solution please

Edit:

When prod have result:
[image]

```
  public product(id: string): Observable<Product> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('id', id);
    urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.product), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        console.log(res)
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          return res.StatusDescription;
        } else {
          return new Product(null);

        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: `===` does strict type checking, Use `==` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are already partially correct, but you need to do a bit more to make it work, and it is to much for a comment.
First, as suggested you want to check the length of your arry

```
<p *ngIf="prod.length == 0"> No result! </p>
```

But to make this visible, you need to put it outside of the for loop.

```
<p *ngIf="prod.length == 0"> No result! </p>
<table *ngFor="let item of prod">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.id}}<td>
        <td>{{item.name}}<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Next, the for loop will break if you don't give it an array. In your case, if there are no results, `StatusDescription` is a string. You need to add a check for this.

```
getallproduct() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.ws.product(params['id']).subscribe(
          products=> {

            this.prod = products == 'No result' ? [] : products;
            console.log(products) // show all product or No result
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'Products' and 'strings' --> Show in my code

Comment: This is a typing error. Your definition of what `this.ws.product` returns probably doesn't cover the case of it being a string when there are no products.

Comment: `Observable<Product>` should be `Observable<Product[]>`. And then, instead of this `return new Product(null);` just return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Unless if its a string use ==

```
<p *ngIf="prod == 0"> No result! </p>
```

Based on the question, you should use prod.length, since prod is an array.

```
<p *ngIf="prod.length == 0"> No result! </p>
```

Comment: there is no change for me. Nothing happens when I write <p *ngIf="prod.length == 0"> No result! </p> When <p *ngIf="prod.length !== 0"> No result! </p> show this message

Comment: In console show this error. ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'No result' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`prod` is an array, not a number.

You should check `*ngIf="prod.length === 0"`

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can try this**

**TS:**
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = '';
  prod = [
    {id: 1, name: 'karthi'},
    {id: 2, name: 'vijay'},
  ];
}


**HTML:**
<div *ngIf="prod.length">
<table *ngFor="let item of prod">
 <tr>
   <td>{{item.id}}<td>
   <td>{{item.name}}<td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<p *ngIf="!prod.length"> No result! </p>
```